# How to wrap and align text centrally using textblock in WPF, that it fill bottom line first?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a very long text and I want to warp it and align it centrally with in a textblock.
I am using `TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"`
and it show like:

[image]

And what I want is:

[image]

So is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: I do not think you can wrap the text like that, wrapping happens only when the end of width is reached. If you use WrapWithOverflow" then the text will not appear until a space is met.

Comment: You can do it from code, question is do you want to dive in?

Comment: @Mishka if have a solution please answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from TextBlock, and handle when the Text property is changing.

The assumption is that when Text property will change, it recieves new value from the Binding.

Then, you construct Run elements and add them to the TextBlock Inlines collection.
You first measure each complete word in the text using FormattedText class to get its width.

If its larger then the width of the control you can break it into two Run elements and place a line break between them.

Comment: FormattedText doc:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx#Anchor_6